# How to freeze a row until a similar row shows up on Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I would like to make an effect similar to how for example iOS apps persist a table's row until someone has scrolled beside it.

[image: Google Sheets example]

## example

This behavior happens all the time in iOS apps. You can see it in the iOS contacts page:

[image: ios-01]
[image: ios-02]
[image: ios-03]

Comment: This is not something that Google Sheets do.

Comment: The most similar that could done is to hide the rows by using the corresponding command or a script but not on scrolling down.

Comment: @404 that's why I'm asking the question.. A script can probably do the trick

Comment: No it can't. Scripts do not have a way to tell which rows are currently visible in your browser's window.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Is it possible to freeze multiple separate rows in Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/106187/33787)

Answer (score 0):

Something similar is possible using Excel by changing what is stored in the top row of your worksheet depending on what row is selected:

Source: [Switching Headers in a Frozen Row](https://excel.tips.net/T003446_Switching_Headers_in_a_Frozen_Row.html) & [Freezing a header row until another header scrolls on screen](https://superuser.com/questions/793838/freezing-a-header-row-until-another-header-scrolls-on-screen)

But as you can see, it is difficult to have that working even inside Excel. So it would seem that this is outside the scope of Google Sheets.