# Is it possible to freeze multiple separate rows in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Currently, Google Sheets can be used to "freeze" sections of a document so that those sections always persist when scrolling, as demonstrated [in this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLJiRD9hu5k). However, a limitation of this is that only one section can be selected, and it must be relative to the beginning of the document, whether it's defined in rows or columns.

Is it at all possible to freeze a second, separate row further down the spreadsheet so that, when scrolling, the first frozen row persists at the top of the sheet until the second frozen row is encountered and replaces the first?

Comment: Related/duplicate: [How to freeze a row until a similar row shows up on Google Sheets?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/91388/33787)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unfortunately not. Google sheets's freeze feature is pretty basic, and only supports freezing one section from the top (or left) of the spreadsheet to your desired endpoint.

If you select a column or row and look in the menu, under View > Freeze, you can see that you can't freeze individual rows/columns, you can only freeze UP TO a certain row/column.

Answer (score 6):

No.

Pivot table could potentially be the closest to the functionality you seemingly want.

Answer (score 0):

I've grouped large sections of rows into different groups to get a similar result... it still doesn't allow for the "scrolling" feature, but the -/+ buttons on the groups work well enough for what I've been trying to do